# Value of type 'UITableViewCell?' has no member 'delegate'

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates, swift3, nib

I am creating a custom delegate in my `TableViewCell` class and calling it in tableView class, but don't know why this error is coming.

**TableView Class :-**

```
 //Cell For Row at indexPath
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    if (0 == indexPath.section)
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FirstRowCell") as! FirstRowCell
        cell.btnReview.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GotoReview), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

        //cell.
        return cell
    }

    else if ( 1 == indexPath.section)
    {
        let identifier = "TableCollectionCell"
        var tableCollectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)
        if(tableCollectionCell == nil)
        {
            let nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("TableCollectionCell", owner: self, options: nil)!
            tableCollectionCell = nib[0] as! TableCollectionCell

            //Delegate
            tableCollectionCell.delegate = self

        }

        return tableCollectionCell!
    }

    else
    {
        let identifier = "BrandImagesTableCell"
        var brandImagesTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier)
        if(brandImagesTableCell == nil)
          {
            let nib:Array = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("BrandImagesTableCell", owner: self, options: nil)!
            brandImagesTableCell = nib[0] as? BrandImagesTableCell
          }
        return brandImagesTableCell!
    }
}


extension HomeViewController : CollectionViewCellTap
{
  func didTapCollectionViewCell(indexPath: Int) {
    let gotoCreateGroup =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CreateGroupView") as! CreateGroupView

    self.present(gotoCreateGroup, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Calling from TableViewCell class :-

```
  protocol CollectionViewCellTap
  {
   func didTapCollectionViewCell(indexPath : Int)

  }

  class TableCollectionCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

var delegate : CollectionViewCellTap?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    //collectionView cell
    collectionView!.register(UINib(nibName: "CreateGroupCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CreateGroupCell")
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}

 }

  //Collection View
 extension TableCollectionCell : UICollectionViewDataSource ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
 {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,  numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return 4
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CreateGroupCell", for: indexPath) as! CreateGroupCell

    cell.groupName.text = ""
    CreateCardView(viewCorner: cell.cardView)

    if(0 == indexPath.row)
    {
        //cell.btnDotted.tag = indexPath.row
        //cell.btnShare.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnDotted.setImage(UIImage(named: "Info"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        cell.btnShare.setImage(UIImage(named : "AddGroup"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    else if(indexPath.row >= 1 && indexPath.row <= 3)
    {
        cell.btnDotted.isHidden = true
        cell.btnShare.isHidden = true
        cell.groupImage.image = UIImage(named: "group_dull_card.png")
    }

    else
    {

    }

    return cell
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if ( 0 == indexPath.row) {

       delegate?.didTapCollectionViewCell(indexPath: indexPath.row)
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: 200, height: 150)
}
}
```

I am new in iOS.

Comment: can you share error?

Comment: That error only I mentioned in question.

Comment: hey issue is `TableCollectionCell`, when you creating cell object it is not taking as TableCollectionCell custom class object. Simply add as? TableCollectionCell while creating object.

Comment: Great it works for me.
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760862/how-to-set-auto-layout-constraint-on-imageview-for-good-resolution-image

I have this query also please help me.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the type of `CustomTableCell` when you are initiating cell object with `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:)` other wise it consider as `UITableViewCell`'s  object that doesn't have property `delegate`, so simply add `as! TableCollectionCell` at the end, so now you are able to access the property of class `TableCollectionCell`.

```
var tableCollectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier) as? TableCollectionCell
```

Comment: I put it but warning is coming :-
 "Comparing non-optional value of type 'TableCollectionCell' to nil always returns false"

Comment: Comparing 
if(tableCollectionCell == nil)

Comment: Ok let me check
Thanks

Comment: Thank you :-)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40760862/how-to-set-auto-layout-constraint-on-imageview-for-good-resolution-image 
I have this query also please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**Check This -**

I think you are missing this

[image]